# Piping browserify with uglify and exorcist in npm scripts

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, uglifyjs, source-maps

I need help to run a chain of commands in `npm` scripts when building a `js` application.

Right now Im running this line:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-js": "browserify src/app/main.js --debug | exorcist dist/app.js.map > dist/app.js",
}
```

That browserifies and extracts sourcemaps. But I would also like to minify with `uglifyjs2`.

How to I pipe uglifyjs to get a minified source with external sourcemaps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`uglifyify`](https://github.com/hughsk/uglifyify) can help you:

```
browserify -t uglifyify src/app/main.js --debug | exorcist dist/app.js.map > dist/app.js
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
"browserify": "browserify -e scripts/index.js -d -t browserify-shim | exorcist scripts/bundle.map | uglifyjs -cm > scripts/bundle.js"
```